# Validate node having same name in tree view at level zero

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

```
Tree
   |
    A-A1
     -A2
   |
    B-B1
     -B2
     -B3
    |
    C-C1
     -C2


        private void treeView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode tn in treeView1.Nodes)
        {
            if (!tn.Equals(e.Node) && tn.Text.ToUpper() == e.Label.ToUpper() )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Name already available for parent. Cannot give same name.", "Rename element");
                e.CancelEdit = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        string l_strOldDisplayName = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => RenameTreeElement(l_strOldDisplayName, e.Node)));
        treeView1.LabelEdit = false;
        treeView1.SelectedNode.EndEdit(false);
        }
        private void RenameElement(string f_strOldDisplayName, TreeNode updatedNode)
        {                           

            foreach (TreeNode currentNode in treeView1.Nodes)
            {
                if (currentNode.Level == 0)
                {
                    if (updatedNode.Text == currentNode.Text)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Name already available for parent. Cannot give same name.", "Rename element");
                        return;
                    }
                }                  
            }
}
```

I am renaming the tree node(A to B) at level 0 (A,B,C) but B is already present in treeview at that time i want to show message "Name already available for parent. Cannot give same name."

for that i have written above code but it is failed for when i give parent node name say 'A' to any child node in the tree it is not allowing..It should allow because parent name may be repeated in children

**Updated code........**

```
void treeView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e) {
  foreach (TreeNode tn in treeView1.Nodes) {
    if (!tn.Equals(e.Node) && tn.Text == e.Label&& !IsChildNodeHaveSameName(e.Label, e.Node)) {
      MessageBox.Show("Name already in use.");
      e.CancelEdit = true;
    }
  }
}

 private bool IsChildNodeHaveSameName(string newName)
        {//if new parent node name is under child node then skip
            foreach (var node in Collect(treeView1.Nodes))
            {
                if (node.Text.ToUpper() == newName.ToUpper())
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        IEnumerable<TreeNode> Collect(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
            {
                yield return node;

                foreach (var child in Collect(node.Nodes))
                    yield return child;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `e.Label` property gives you the text that the user is writing in the floating label.  With that, you can simplify your code into something like this:

```
void treeView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Node.Level == 0) {
    foreach (TreeNode tn in treeView1.Nodes) {
      if (!tn.Equals(e.Node) && tn.Text == e.Label) {
        MessageBox.Show("Name already in use.");
        e.CancelEdit = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when i give parent node name say 'A' to any child node in the tree it is not allowing..It should allow because parent name should be repeated in children

Comment: @John Updated code.  Sounds like you only want to have this check to happen on the root notes.